# jquery checkbox

Tags: jquery

I have 3 checkboxes , I want to attach the click event on 2 but not the third . I am writing

```
<input type=checkbox />
<input type=checkbox />
<input type=checkbox id='selectAll' />
```

Script:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox:not(input#selectAll)').click(function(){
  ///my code comes here 
});
```

The problem is click event is getting attached to all the checkboxes . I do not want the click event to get attached to the checkbox with id = selectAll.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have works, [you can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ewKuw/). Make sure some *other* event handler isn't getting attached that you don't want...or some other event isn't causing an event interaction with the "checkAll".

Also, be sure to always quote your attributes ([like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ewKuw/1/))!, not doing so *can* have side-effects if there are any special characters/spaces, and it's just good practice anyway.